# How to remove duplicate letters using sed?

Tags: text-processing, sed

Using sed, how can I remove duplicate letters from HEADERS within a text file?

```
NNAAMMEE
       nice - run a program with modified scheduling priority

SSYYNNOOPPSSIISS
       nice     [-n    adjustment]    [-adjustment]    [--adjustment=adjustment] [command [a$
```

Above is a an example.  I want the output after parsing with `sed` to be:

```
NAME
       nice - run a program with modified scheduling priority

SYNOPSIS
       nice     [-n    adjustment]    [-adjustment]    [--adjustment=adjustment] [command [a$
```

Comment: So only two and no more consecutive instances of a letter to be converted to one?

Comment: The example looks like a "broken" man page. How did you come to that?

Comment: With perl you could do: `perl -pe 's/([A-Z])\1/$1/g'`

Comment: Thanks all for feedback.  @1_CR Specifically just the headers, and not the rest of the text.

Comment: @michas It's just an example I found online. I'm trying to learn how to use sed effectively.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

#### Method #1

You can use this `sed` command to do it:

```
$ sed 's/\([A-Za-z]\)\1\+/\1/g' file.txt
```

#### Example

Using your above sample input I created a file, `sample.txt`.

```
$ sed 's/\([A-Za-z]\)\1\+/\1/g' sample.txt 
NAME
       nice - run a program with modified scheduling priority

       SYNOPSIS
              nice     [-n    adjustment]    [-adjustment] [--adjustment=adjustment] [command [a$
```

#### Method #2

There is also this method which will remove all the duplicate characters:

```
$ sed 's/\(.\)\1/\1/g' file.txt
```

#### Example

```
$ sed 's/\(.\)\1/\1/g' sample.txt 
NAME
    nice - run a program with modified scheduling priority

    SYNOPSIS
       nice   [-n  adjustment]  [-adjustment] [-adjustment=adjustment] [command [a$
```

#### Method #3 (just the upper case)

The OP asked if you could modify it so that only the upper case characters would be removed, here's how using a modified method #1.

#### Example

```
$ sed 's/\([A-Z]\)\1\+/\1/g' sample.txt 
NAME
       nice - run a program with modified scheduling priority

       SYNOPSIS
              nice     [-n    adjustment]    [-adjustment] [--adjustment=adjustment] [command [a$
```

#### Details of the above methods

All the examples make use of a technique where when a character is first encountered that's in the set of characters A-Z or a-z that it's value is saved. Wrapping parens around characters tells `sed` to save them for later.  That value is then stored in a temporary variable that you can access either immediately or later on. These variables are named \1 and \2.

So the trick we're using is we match the first letter.

```
\([A-Za-z]\)
```

Then we turn around and use the value that we just saved as a secondary character that must occur right after the first one above, hence:

```
\([A-Za-z]\)\1.
```

In `sed` we're also making use of the search and replace facility, `s/../../g`. The `g` means we're doing it globally.

So when we encounter a character, followed by another one, we substitute it out, and replace it with just one of the same character.

Comment: Thank you.  Rremoving all duplicates isn't what I want to do; e.g., "command" should stay "command" but "NNAAMMEE" should become "NAME"   is there a way to use sed with 's/\(.\)\1/\1/g' but only for double-capitals?

Comment: @JonSmith - you could take the first example and remove the a-z bit from the set of characters. `sed 's/\([A-Z]\)\1\+/\1/g'`

Comment: To do it in just headers, add `/^[A-Z]/` - `sed '/^[A-Z]/s/\(.\)\1/\1/g'`

Comment: Can you explain what the parenthesis are for?  How is [A-Z] different from \([A-Z]\)    Also, what is the + operator for?   The \1 is for pattern matching, correct?

Comment: @slm I knew only basic of `sed`, this answer is amazing, but can you please explain. like what is meaning of `\1`

Comment: @RahulPatil - thanks for asking. I've updated the answer with a description of what's going on, let me know if it's good enough.

Answer (score 3):

This command removes all double letters:

```
sed 's/\([[:alpha:]]\)\1/\1/g'
```

`\1` stands for the text inside `\(…\)`, so this command means: wherever there's an alphabetical character followed by itself, replace by that alphabetical character alone.

That will transform e.g. `command` into `comand`. It would be better to restrict the transformation to where it's needed: non-indented lines.

```
sed '/^[[:alpha:]]/ s/\([[:alpha:]]\)\1/\1/g'
```

This text is a man page rendered for terminals where bold is represented by overstrike: `C\bC` is rendered as bold, where `\b` is the backspace character (character number 8, also known as ^H). If the control characters are still there, forget about duplicate letters and instead remove the overstrike.

```
sed -e 's/.\b//g'
```

If you have a way to format the output, transofmr `C\bC` to bold and `_\bC` to underline.

```
sed -e 's/\(.\)\b\1/\e[1m\1\e[22m/g' -e 's/_\b\(.\)/\e[4m\1\e[24m/g' |
sed -e 's/\e[22m\e[1m//g' -e 's/\e[24m\e[4m//g'
```

If your sed doesn't understand backslash escapes, use the literal characters (Ctrl+H for `\b` and Ctrl+[ for `\e`).

Answer (score 2):

This is by no means a trivial task. A simple substitution for letter doubles would be disastrous. Think of what it would do to words like "attention" or "forgetting" or (more relevant to your case) "command". The script below is a naive first try at a solution. It makes use of a dictionary to determine which words really have duplicate letters.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

my $input_file = shift//die "No file name given\n";
my $dictionary = shift//'/usr/share/dict/words';
open my $if,'<',$input_file or die "$input_file: $!\n";
open my $dict,'<',$dictionary or die "$dictionary: $!\n";
my %dictionary;
for(<$dict>){
    chomp;
    $dictionary{$_}++;
}
close $dictionary;

LINE: while(<$if>){
    chomp;

    WORD: for my $word ( split /\s+/ ){
            print "$word " and next WORD if exists $dictionary{lc $word};

            SUBSTITUTION: while($word=~ s{([A-Z])\1}{$1}i){
                exists $dictionary{lc $word} and last SUBSTITUTION;
            } #END SUBSTITUTION
            print "$word ";

     } #END WORD

     print "\n";

} #END LINE
```

Call it like

```
[user@host]./myscript.pl input_file optional_dictionary_file >output_file
```

If you don't supply a second argument, the dictionary file defaults to `/usr/share/dict/words`, which should be available on a decent GNU/Linux.

**Disclaimer:** This is untested.

**Caveats:**

- It will break at least with hyphenated words (it uses spaces to decide what a "word" is).
- It will only remove duplicated capitals to avoid messing with the contents of the `man` page themselves.
- It will wreak havoc on hexadecimals like `0xFFFF`.
- Probably many more that I can't see.

Comment: I agree removing all duplicates isn't what I want to do; e.g., "commands" should stay "commands" but "NNAAMMEE" should become "NAME"

Comment: @JonSmith ... and what should the header `SSHHEELLLL GGRRAAMMMMAARR` (from a supposedly broken man bash page) become?

Answer (score 1):

It seems you're example is from man-pages.

MAN was originally designed on teletype. For bold the sequence then is XX. The  probably got lost in your output to the editor, hence the double characters.

vi can easily remove these.

See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26634497/redirecting-man-page-output-to-file-results-in-double-letters-in-words

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
sed -e 's/\([A-Za-z]\)\1/\1/g'
```

Just remove the `\\+`, then only doubled letters are reduced to a single letter. (Works assuming all characters have been duplicated)

Try this little test:

```
echo "PPaayy Atttteenttiioonn ttoo aallll ccoommmmaanndds" > test.txt
sed -e 's/\([A-z]\)\1/\1/g' < test.txt > test2.txt
cat test2.txt
```

Comment: The OP later qualified that they only wanted title text [A-Z] de-duplicated. Also, your 2nd sed command needs an edit to the range "A-z"

Answer (score 0):

You can restrict the changes to the affected strings with something like this:

```
eval sed $(
for i in NAME SYNOPSIS DESCRIPTION "RETURN VALUE" ENVIRONMENT FILES EXAMPLES DIAGNOSTICS ERRORS "SEE ALSO" "CONFORMING TO" HISTORY AUTHORS BUGS; do
  dup=$(for j in $(seq 0 ${#i}); do printf "%s%s" "${i:j:1}" "${i:j:1}"; done)
  printf " -e \"s/%s/%s/\"" "$dup" "$i"
done)
```

Answer (score 0):

In Python :

**Method 1#**
Using Own Function :

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
from __future__ import print_function
import sys

def RemoveDupliChar(Word):
        NewWord = " "
        index = 0
        for char in Word:
               if char != NewWord[index]:
                       NewWord += char
                       index += 1
        print(NewWord.strip())

with open(sys.argv[1],'r') as InputFile:
        for line in InputFile:
                if line.isupper():
                        RemoveDupliChar(line)
                else:
                        print(line,end='')
```

**Method 2#**
Using [itertools.groupby](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby):

Thanks to @[falstretu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18799036/python-best-way-to-remove-duplicate-character-from-string?answertab=votes#tab-top)

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
from __future__ import print_function
import itertools
import sys

with open(sys.argv[1],'r') as InputFile:
        for line in InputFile:
                if line.isupper():
                        print(''.join(ch for ch, _ in itertools.groupby(line)))
                else:
                        print(line,end='')
```

**Execution :**

```
root@ubuntu:~# python remove_duplicate_char.py Input.txt
NAME
       nice - run a program with modified scheduling priority

SYNOPSIS
       nice     [-n    adjustment]    [-adjustment]    [--adjustment=adjustment] [command [a$
```